# Best Machine Learning package for Python 3x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was bummed out to see that scikit-learn does not support Python 3...Is there a comparable package anyone can recommend for Python 3?

Comment: Scikit-learn supports Python3 via python2to3. Didn't that work? There is also work on single-codebase Python3 support, which should be done soon.

Comment: the 2to3 build does not completely work completely in scikit-learn yet. I might work on this during the next sprint in september.

Comment: Has not been done yet. However the next version of joblib will work natively with python 2.6+ and 3.2+ with the same code base which will make it easier for scikit-learn to do the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you look for scikits-learn on Windows there are [binary installers for 3.2 32&64 bits](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn)

Answer (score 12):

Try either of these, both are supported by python 3

1. http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/
2. http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep the thread open for a bit longer in case anyone else wants to chime in.

Comment: mdp actually includes scikit-learn for many of the algorithms. It would be weird if it would work but not scikit-learn.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, Scikit-Learn is supported by Python3 now.